# How to find GPS coordinates of a known distance from a known gps location?

Tags: gps, location

I need to know a method to find GPS coordinates of an unknown point.
Following is my scenario.

I know the GPS coordinates of location A.
I want to find the GPS coordinates of a location B(unknown) with a known D distance from location A.
(I also know the direction of location B)
I am so grateful if you could please help me with this.
Thanks in advance,
Hasala

Comment: What did you try? How do you express the direction vector?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I thought of using the angle from North. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you use polar coordinates, with first transforming to cartesian (x,y) coordinates, and then back to spheric, or you use this formula:

[Lat Lon given radial and distance](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL)